# Strange Datamapper's behaviour

Tags: sinatra, haml, datamapper

I have this code in my controller:

```
 @cats = DirCat.all
```

And this in a view:

```
  %ul#menu
    = @cats.each do |item|
      %li
        = link_to item.title, "/catalog/#{item.id}/"
```

And get strange output:

```
    <ul id='menu'>
      <li>
        <a href="/catalog/4/">hello</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/catalog/5/">hello 1</a>
      </li>
    #<DataMapper::Collection:0x85a9d00>
    </ul>
```

In the irb console:

```
irb(main):002:0> c.each { |item| puts item.title }
hello
hello 1
=> [#<DirCat @id=4 @parent_id=1 @title="hello">, #<DirCat @id=5 @parent_id=1 @title="hello 1">]
```

How can I get out `#<DataMapper::Collection:0x85a9d00>` from my html?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In HAML, `=` is used to display the output of a thing in your markup.  `#<DataMapper::Collection:0x85a9d00>` is the return value of `@cats.each do |item|`.  You want to use `-`, which executes code (but does not print the return value):

```
- @cats.each do |item|
   %li
     = link_to item.title, "/catalog/#{item.id}/"
```

Comment: Oooops… I haven't noticed this thing. Thx a lot!